# CF accepts JSON string in cf2016 but not in cf9

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-2016

I am calling an API and need to send it a JSON string with credentials. We are currently transitioning from CF9 to CF2016. In DEVL I have both versions. In Test and Prod I currently have CF9 only. Originally I wrote the code and tested on CF2016 and it worked fine. When I pushed it up to Test, it did not work. I retried in DEVL, on CF9, and it also errors. The code is:

```
<cfset logininfo = {"username": "eistech", "password": "#sat_pw#"}> 
<cfset fromdate=dateformat(DateAdd('d', -1, dat), "yyyy-MM-dd") & 'T00:00:00-0500'>

<!--- Get token info--->
<cfhttp url="https://scoresdownload.collegeboard.org/pascoredwnld/files/list?fromDate=#fromdate#" method="post"  result="finfo">
    <cfhttpparam name="Content-Type" type="HEADER" value="application/json">
    <cfhttpparam name="Accept" type="HEADER" value="application/json">
     <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(logininfo)#">
</cfhttp>
```

When running it in CF9, I get:

> Invalid CFML construct found on line 5 at column 20. ColdFusion was
>   looking at the following text: 
>   `{ (Line 20 is <cfset logininfo =
>   {"username": "eistech", "password": "#sat_pw#"}>`

I tried enclosing it in single quotes, but this fails in both instances. How can I get this to work in both CF2016 and CF9?

Comment: CF9 does nor understand `:` as used in JSON. Use `=`! `<cfset logininfo = {"username"= "eistech", "password"= "#sat_pw#"}> `

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Enter that as the answer, please. Also note that `logininfo` is not "JSON", in that syntax from CF's point of view, that's an implicit struct.

Comment: I would also not recommend using CF2016 in Dev and CF9 in Production. Make the environments match. If you need to test, Create a Test environment that runs 2016 that you can deploy from Dev. You will lose so much in 2016 if you try to write it for CF9 compatibility. As seen above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CF9 does not understand `:` as used in the JSON string in the question. 
Use `=`!

```
<cfset logininfo = {"username"= "eistech", "password"= "#sat_pw#"}>
```

Comment: Adding to it: The colon syntax was introduced in CF10.